# Priority of a query in MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Is there a way to tell MS SQL that a query is not too important and that it can (and should) take its time?

Likewise is there a way to tell MS SQL that it should give higher priority to a query?

Comment: Weird question since a long running query can potentially cause more locking.

Comment: long running queries should be created in a manner where locking is minimalized.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Not in versions below SQL 2008. In SQL Server 2008 there's the resource governor. Using that you can assign logins to groups based on properties of the login (login name, application name, etc). The groups can then be assigned to resource pools and limitations or restrictions i.t.o. resources can be applied to those resource pools

Comment: Note this feature is only available in Enterprise and Developer editions.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server does not have any form of resource governor yet. There is a SET option called QUERY_GOVERNOR_COST_LIMIT but it's not quite what you're looking for. And it prevents queries from executing based on the cost rather than controlling resources.

Comment: SQL Server 2008 includes a very complete resource governor.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you're asking, but I had a situation where a single UI click added 10,000 records to an email queue (lots of data in the body).  The email went out over the next several days so it didn't need to be a high priority, in fact it would bog the server every time it happened.

I split the procedure into 10,000 individual calls, ran the process on the UI in a different thread (set to low priority) and set it to sleep for a second after running the procedure.  It took a while, but I had very granular control over exactly what it was doing.

btw, this was NOT spam, so don't flame me thinking it was.

Comment: I don't think that setting thread priority in client affects the session/command priority on SQL server.

Comment: Unclear if you mean a stored procedure on SQL, or a procedure in a client application that is calling SQL