# Limit resources available to query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, resources

I want to limit the system resources available to queries run by specific users in SQL Server 2008.
Some queries are seemingly running away with all the resources of the machine causing the server to become unresponsive.
My thought process is that if there is a way to cap the amount of resources (mem/cpu cycles/bw) a query can grab, this problem would go away.
Is this possible? Are there better techniques to accomplish this?

This is MS Sql Server 2008,

Comment: Better techniques? Like perhaps identifying the problem queries and improving them? Limiting resource usage is only treating the symptom, since the problem queries will still fail.

Comment: Did you had a chance to look at this question (may be not answering your question but possibly could help) ? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60878/priority-of-a-query-in-ms-sql

Comment: Are these ad-hoc queries that users can type in or are they program generated queries?   Are any tables using Blobs?   We had one application where a blob field held a large presentation file.  select * from that table really hung the server

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're running the Enterprise Edition, you could take a look at the [Resource Governor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933866.aspx).

Comment: Resource Governor is also available in the Developer Edition.

Comment: @RickNZ Developer Edition is functionally equivalent to Enterprise.