# how can we run sql query in background

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to know how can we run sql query in background ... I have a big query which is taking so much time I want to run this as background so that my page loading time will be less..

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60878/priority-of-a-query-in-ms-sql

Answer (score 4):

Run the query in a PHP script using cron and cache the result.

Answer (score 4):

You could call your queries in separate scripts with AJAX.  When the page is requested, process PHP as normal, render and send the page to the visitor, and immediately kick off an AJAX script requesting another PHP script that executes the slow query.  The page will be loading while the query runs, and when you get the results back from your query, use a little JavaScript to incorporate the results.  The gain here is that while the page is loading the query is running, so you're doing both at once.

Also look at optimizing your query and ensure that you have set an index on your tables to speed up the query.

Comment: This won't be a solution for queries you always want to execute.What happens if the user disables javascript or uses a browser that doesn't support javascript?

Comment: No, this is a solution for a slow running "background" request.  If you want it done right away, hit a different endpoint.  We're talking about two different things.  As for JavaScript being disabled, you will probably have to inform the user that they have lost functionality because of their choice.  A webapp with some sophistication, like running queries on the server while the user does something else, is either going to have JavaScript or require the user to refresh and see if the query is done.  There's nothing wrong with making JavaScript a requirement to get full functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Some solutions here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/table-locking.html and here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html.

The official mySQL site says:

```
INSERT [LOW_PRIORITY | DELAYED | HIGH_PRIORITY] [INTO] tbl_name [(col_name,...)]
{VALUES | VALUE} ({expr | DEFAULT},...),(...),...
```

so a real use case would look like

```
INSERT LOW_PRIORITY INTO tablename (column1,column2) VALUES ("hello","you");
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest the CRON and Cache approach, or implement the use of AJAX.

With CRON and Cache, run your query, then serialize it and save it to a file for sanity. Call and unserialize when needed.

With AJAX, when your page loads, make a call to a file which executes and returns the query. This way, you can display a waiting indicator while your server runs the query and they are separate from eachother.

Answer (score 0):

Write the query in your PHP file and schedule it at time or time interval when you want to run it. For linux schedule [CRON](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ucrontab.htm) or Windows use [Task Scheduler](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569) Else You can trigger it by [Ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp) request