# Force server to allocate Server's core execute the stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, windows-server-2008

I got a question regarding SQL Server,

I just wanted to know, is that possible to request the server to allocate the core to work more for one stored procedural? If it's possible how can I do that, and show me the way.

Thank you

Comment: Possibly following question gives an answer: [Priority of a query in MS SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60878/priority-of-a-query-in-ms-sql)

Comment: Hey thanks much for your help, indeed the answer was there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60878/priority-of-a-query-in-ms-sql)

And I think the best way to allocate the server based on user group and pool resources.

Thanks