# Max degree of parallelism (MAXDOP) at user level

Tags: sql-server

Quite  a quick one, it is possible to set MAXDOP setting at user level?

So all queries ran by user A will use MAXDOP(2) whilst all other users use MAXDOP(x) (server default).

If not, any suggestions to restrict server resources from a single user?

Comment: Perhaps this would be better asked at dba.se?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Priority of a query in MS SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60878/priority-of-a-query-in-ms-sql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there is an option built into the language other than `OPTION MAXDOP` for specific queries. Perhaps if the users you want to restrict only user certain queries this may be of use to you.

If you are on an Enterprise edition of SQL Server, then perhaps Resource Governor may cover your requirements:

[- MSDN on Resource Governor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933866.aspx)

[- An example running through setting resource restrictions for different users](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/06/04/sql-server-simple-example-to-configure-resource-governor-introduction-to-resource-governor/)